# Selecting checkboxes based on part of name/id

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have cakephp model structure of document->section->variables

I have been advised that my question relates to javascript/jQuery rather than cakePHP.  Apologies if people are having to re-read this from previous cakephp question.

In a form I want to be able to list all variables, but nested within document and then section levels. That bit is fine.

I want check boxes alongside each item at the variable level - to allow selection of variables.

I want a checkbox at sectionlevel, that when selected will select all the checkboxes for the variables in that section.

I want a checkbox at document level so that when selected it will select all checkboxes for the variables for that document (ie in all sections.)

To facilitate this I have named the checkboxes thus (well, I have set the ids)(pseudo code):

```
document level: id = Document id
section level: id = Document id_Section id
variable level: id = Document id_Section id_Variable_id
```

My hope this that if I select the section level checkbox I can set all the variable level checkboxes FOR THAT SECTION by using the Document id_Section_id stub at the beginning of all the ids for the variable level checkboxes... but maybe I am grasping at straws?

Here is a sample of checkboxes in levels: (apologies for layout)

```
<?php
//Document level

//all of this within a ForEach loop for documents

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>Collection dates</td><td>".$project_document['data_collection_dates']."</td>";
echo "<td>Select (toggle) all variables"
        .$this->Form->checkbox($project_document['id'], // note that this sets the chkbox id to the value of the current document id
                            array('hiddenField' => false,'onclick'=> 'SelectSection(this,this.name,this.checked);'))
                            ."</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";

foreach ($project_document['ProjectDocumentSection'] as $project_document_section): 
    echo "<h4>" .  $project_document_section['title']. "</h4>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><td>Collection Method</td><td>" . $project_document_section['method']. "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Collection objective</td><td>" . $project_document_section['objective']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>Select (toggle) all section variables"
            .$this->Form->checkbox($project_document['id']
                ."_".$project_document_section['id'] // and here the chkbox id is set to combination of document id and section is (using _ as separator)
                , array('hiddenField' => false))."</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
        echo "<table><tr><th>Full text</th><th>Type</th><th>Format</th><th>Codeset</th></tr>" ; // header for variable table
        foreach ($project_document_section['ProjectDocumentSectionVariable'] as $project_document_section_var):
            echo"<tr><td>".$project_document_section_var['variable_type'] 
                            ."</td><td>".$project_document_section_var['variable_format'] 
                            ."</td><td>";
            echo "<td>".$this->Form->checkbox($project_document['id']
                    ."_".$project_document_section['id']
                        ."_".$project_document_section_var['id'], array('hiddenField' => false))."</td></tr>";
        endforeach;
        echo "</table>";

endforeach;
// and later endforeach for the document itself

?>
```

And when rendered this might look something like this;

```
<td>Select (toggle) all variables
<input type="checkbox" name="data[Project][11]"  onclick="SelectSection(this,this.name,this.checked);" value="1" id="Project11"/>
// note that checkbox id and name include ref to document id (11)
</td></tr>

<h4>Details of Health Workers at Facility</h4>

<table>
 <tr><td>Collection Method</td><td>FW completed evaluation on paper</td></tr>
<tr><td>Collection objective</td><td>blah blah blah blah</td>
<td>Select (toggle) all section variables
<input type="checkbox" name="data[Project][11_24]"  value="1" id="Project1124"/></td></tr>
// note that checkbox id and name include ref to document id (11) and section id (24)
</table>
<table>
<tr><th>Full text</th><th>Type</th><th>Format</th><th>Codeset</th></tr>
<tr><td>Site</td><td>Categorical</td><td>Quantative</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[Project][11_24_402]"  value="1" id="Project1124402"/></td></tr>
// note that checkbox id and name include ref to document id (11), section id (24) and variable id (402)
<tr><td>Facility</td><td>Categorical</td><td>Quantative</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[Project][11_24_403]"  value="1" id="Project1124403"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Text</td><td>Quantative</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[Project][11_24_404]"  value="1" id="Project1124404"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Position of Health Worker</td><td>Text</td><td>Quantative</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[Project][11_24_405]"  value="1" id="Project1124405"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Description</td><td>Text</td><td>Quantative</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[Project][11_24_406]"  value="1" id="Project1124406"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Interviewer Code</td><td>Categorical</td><td>Quantative</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[Project][11_24_407]"  value="1" id="Project1124407"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Date of Facility Visit </td><td>Date</td><td>Quantative</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[Project][11_24_408]"  value="1" id="Project1124408"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

Has anyone any advice on how to approach this? I am sure there is more than one way to kill this bird..

Comment: Your question is hard to read.

Comment: Give them a common class or use the prefix selector.

Comment: since this is a javascript/html question, it would be a good idea for you to remove the PHP code. Too much information will make it difficult for us to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using jQuery [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), more specifically the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)?

Comment: Thanks Chris, I hadn't but will look at this now.

Comment: I have managed to get it to work too! Syntax in javascript function was: $('input:checkbox[id^=' + id + ']').prop('checked', true);  Where id is passed into function.  The ^ was the crux!

Answer (score 1):

The following code selects every `input`, whose `type` attribute is *checkbox* and `name` attribute begins with *data*. It'll then add a class to each corresponding element (in this instance, the class **myNewClass** would be added to each element found.

### Javascript

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name^=data]').addClass('myNewClass');
```

Comment: Working examples are great, but you should also explain why it works.

Comment: @BradKoch Sorry for my laziness on this answer. I have added an explanation. (The joys of rushing answers at the office to help people out haha)

Comment: Thanks Ghillied, this syntax will help.